# Caml query with more than 2 or conditions

Tags: javascript, csom, caml-query, caml

```
var fieldName;


 var listFields;
    var CmalQuery;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {
            txtValue = $('#txtSearch').val();
            ListName =   $('#ddlTitles').val();

             retrieveFieldsOfListView(ListName);

    });
     $('#btnList').on('click', function () {
        GetAllLists();
    });
    /* $('select').on('change', function () {
       ListName = this.value;
       retrieveFieldsOfListView(ListName);
       txtValue = $('#txtSearch').val();
         // or $(this).val()
    });*/    
    });




function GetListData() {


    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

    //Get the list. Alter this code to match the name of your list  
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
    //  context.executeQuerySync(printFieldNames, onError);

    //Create a new CAML query  

    var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
     // CmalQuery="<View><Query><Where><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /><Value Type='Text'>p</Value></Contains><Contains><FieldRef Name='EmpName' /><Value Type='Text'>p</Value></Contains></Or></Where></Query></View>";   //Create the CAML that will return only items with the titles that contains with 'txtValue' 
     caml.set_viewXml(CmalQuery);
    //Specify the query and load the list oject  
      returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);
      context.load(returnedItems);
    //Run the query asynchronously, passing the functions to call when a response arrives  
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail);
    function onQuerySuccess(sender, args) {

        var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();
        //Formulate HTML from the list items  
        var markup = 'Items in the Employee Details list that contains with ' + '"' + txtValue + '"' + ': <br><br><table class="table table-striped">';
               //Loop through all the items  
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
            markup += '<tr><td>' + listItem.get_item(fieldName) + '</td></tr>';
             //markup += '<td>' + listItem.get_item('JobTitle') + '</td>';
            //markup += '<td> ' + listItem.get_item('Title') + '</td> ';
           //markup += '<td>' + listItem.get_item('ManagerName').get_lookupValue() + '</td></tr>';
          //Display the formulated HTML in the displayDiv element  
        }
        markup += '</table>'
        $('#resultsDiv').html(markup);
    }
    function onQueryFail(sender, args) {//Formulate HTML to display details of the error  
        var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';
        markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';
        //Display the details  
        $('#resultsDiv').html(markup);
    }


}

function GetAllLists() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    var oWebsite = context.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    context.load(collList);

    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded,onQueryFailed);
    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var listInfo = '<table class="table table-striped"><tr>';
        var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();

            listInfo += '<tr><td>Title: ' + oList.get_title() + '</td></tr>';

           $("#ddlTitles").append($("<option></option>").html(oList.get_title()));
        }
        listInfo +='</tr></table>'
         $('#resultsDiv').html(listInfo);



    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}


function retrieveFieldsOfListView(ListName) {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle('All Items');
    listFields = view.get_viewFields();
    context.load(listFields);
    context.executeQueryAsync(printFieldNames, onError);


    function printFieldNames() {
    var e = listFields.getEnumerator();
        CmalQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Or>";
        while (e.moveNext()) {
            fieldName = e.get_current();

           CmalQuery += "<Contains><FieldRef Name='"+fieldName+"' /><Value Type='Text'>" + txtValue + "</Value></Contains>";

            console.log(fieldName);

        }
          CmalQuery += "</Or></Where></Query></View>";
          GetListData();
    }

    function onError(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please go through this link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide proper description of your problem so one can understand it

Comment: You have added unnecessary piece of code also. Always target to the point so people can focus on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following block from your code

```
CmalQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Or>";
        while (e.moveNext()) {
            fieldName = e.get_current();

           CmalQuery += "<Contains><FieldRef Name='"+fieldName+"' /><Value Type='Text'>" + txtValue + "</Value></Contains>";

            console.log(fieldName);

        }
          CmalQuery += "</Or></Where></Query></View>";
```

and add this block which will build dynamic query

```
var counter = 0;

CmalQuery = "<View><Query><Where>";
        while (e.moveNext()) {
            fieldName = e.get_current();

           if(counter >0)
               CmalQuery = "<Or>" + CmalQuery;

           CmalQuery += "<Contains><FieldRef Name='"+fieldName+"' /><Value Type='Text'>" + txtValue + "</Value></Contains>";

           if(counter > 0)
               CmalQuery =  CmalQuery + "</Or>";
            counter++;

            console.log(fieldName);

        }
          CmalQuery += "</Where></Query></View>";
```

Comment: You can accept as answer or upvote if helped you.. so people looking for same will be helped